# How to parse a date from string (template needed)

Tags: ruby, date

I have a string like `2015-07-09T12:00:00+00:00`. How can I parse it using `Date.strptime()`? Help me to build a template.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? The documentation for `strptime` covers all the options and has examples. Asking us to help you without having tried anything isn't the Stack Overflow way. Your time format is a standard form, and the [Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html) and [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) documentation cover how to parse it, but it requires reading those documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DateTime.strptime` instead of `Date.strptime`, since you're using time and timezone.